# Как обратиться на прямую к объекту в js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Задача следующая: нужно обратиться на прямую к чекбоксу в js и присвоить ему класс, то есть присвоить класс только чекбоксу, имеющему некий класс который `checked`, а не всем чекбоксам с этим же классом. Что нужно сделать?

```
       function chbFun() {
            if (cogChbox1.checked) {
                $('.table-end').addClass('checked-cog');
            }
            else {
                $('.table-end').removeClass('checked-cog');
            }
        }
```